# Unclear error log in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I don't recall when I started getting this in log output window but it looks like this:

```
[08:37:09.00705- 10692] MyProgram.exe dbglog.cpp(110)       DbgLog_F                       Log for module 'game' (93154) started with process 'MyProgram.exe' (x86, PID: 16632, CmdLine: "R:\Cache\Visual Studio\Debug\MyProgram.exe" ) - Sun Mar 15 08:37:09 2015

[08:37:09.00705- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4642)    LoadCustomCursor               Loading custom cursor from "C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\resources\images\ingame\cursor_pointer.cur"
[08:37:09.00706- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4642)    LoadCustomCursor               Loading custom cursor from "C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\resources\images\ingame\cursor_move.cur"
[08:37:09.00707- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4642)    LoadCustomCursor               Loading custom cursor from "C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\resources\images\ingame\cursor_nwse.cur"
[08:37:09.00707- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4642)    LoadCustomCursor               Loading custom cursor from "C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\resources\images\ingame\cursor_dragdrop.cur"
[08:37:09.00708- 10692] MyProgram.exe dbglog.cpp(204)       OpenGlobalEvent                Global event "Global\ltc_game_candidate_event_16632l" opened, with modification flag.
[08:37:09.00708- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4941)    DllMain                        Current process is an auto-hook candidate
[08:37:09.00710- 10692] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(1912)    StartAutoHookMonitoring        Auto-hook monitoring started
[08:37:09.00710- 10692] MyProgram.exe common.cpp(492)       CreateGlobalEvent              Global event "Global\ltc_load_game_event_16632l" created, with manual reset.
[08:37:09.00710- 10692] MyProgram.exe common.cpp(492)       CreateGlobalEvent              Global event "Global\ltc_unload_game_event_16632l" created, with manual reset.
[08:37:09.00710- 10692] MyProgram.exe dbglog.cpp(204)       OpenGlobalEvent                Global event "Global\ltc_shutdown_event" opened.
[08:37:09.00712- 16988] MyProgram.exe autohook.cpp(244)     AutoHookManager::_WatchForQuitOrTimeoutThread Watching
[08:37:09.00713- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4688)    MainThread                     MainThread executing...
[08:37:09.00713- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Console logging has been enabled.
[08:37:09.00713- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [sta:"StartRecorder"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [stp:"StopRecorder"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [slsk:"SetLiveStreamKey live_37135925_lD9UDVtrXfCT8yf0kHeWdVhaITG9oy"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [srl:"RecorderLog C:\Users\Randal\Desktop\ffmpeg.log"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [twitchtest2:"BroadcasterDebug 1;GetTwitchAuthToken ql7dn49ya6oalq5xux4s33a16n3e7sv RaptrRandal raptrtest"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [twitchtest:"BroadcasterDebug 1;SetTwitchAuthToken 1eduwz3hdp3yprib6vhpr5c64go2nv3;StartBroadcast"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [gfastfb:"GetFramebufferAsSizeFastBench 1"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [dt1:"D3D11FastDumpTest 1"]
[08:37:09.00714- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Console initialised.
[08:37:09.00718- 14172] MyProgram.exe overlayui.cpp(1120)   OverlayUI_InitializeConsole    This game has no on-load flags.
[08:37:09.00720- 18392] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(2311)    ModuleScanThread               ModuleScanThread executing...
[08:37:09.00720- 18392] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(2318)    ModuleScanThread               Process File Name:MyProgram.exe
[08:37:09.00721- 18392] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(2421)    ModuleScanThread               Found Graphics Module:opengl32.dll
[08:37:09.00721- 18392] MyProgram.exe opengl_hook.cpp(1749) DoHooking_OpenGL               Module [opengl32.dll] @ 585D0000.
[08:37:09.00729- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(3460)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [002A0EC6] has been input-enabled.
[08:37:09.00745- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(3460)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [00080F6A] has been input-enabled.
[08:37:09.00834- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(3460)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [004B0F06] has been input-enabled.
[08:37:09.00834- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(3460)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [00231164] has been input-enabled.
[08:37:09.00834- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4741)    MainThread                     Waiting for shutdown event (00000624) or unload event...
The thread 0x4574 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[08:38:09.00712- 16988] MyProgram.exe autohook.cpp(236)     AutoHookManager::_WatchForQuitOrTimeout Timed-out
[08:38:09.00712- 16988] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(1895)    OnAutoHooked                   PID: 16632 timed-out
[08:38:09.00712- 18392] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(2446)    ModuleScanThread               Ending module scan thread...
[08:38:09.00712- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4748)    MainThread                     Unload game module event fired! Cleaning up...
[08:38:09.00713- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4771)    MainThread                     Shutdown capture
[08:38:09.00713- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4777)    MainThread                     Waiting for module scan thread...
The thread 0x47d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x425c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[08:38:09.00785- 14172] MyProgram.exe winapi_hooks.cpp(960) DoHooking_WinAPI               WARNING! Cannot unhook, not hooked!
[08:38:09.00785- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(4844)    MainThread                     Shut down.
[08:38:10.00787- 14172] MyProgram.exe ltc_game.cpp(5031)    DllMain                        DLLMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
[08:38:10.00787- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(91)         CConsole::~CConsole            ERROR! Console window had not been created.
[08:38:10.00787- 14172] MyProgram.exe console.h(100)        CConsole::~CConsole            ERROR! Console widget had not been created.
[08:38:10.00788- 14172] MyProgram.exe ../common/hooks.h(93) CHookMgr::~CHookMgr            Done.
[08:38:10.00788- 14172] MyProgram.exe ../common/crash.h(58) CCrashMgr::~CCrashMgr          CrashMgr shutting down.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? Program continues running normally after this.

Comment: Is there actually an error there?

Comment: Please give us some codes.

Comment: Project is way too big to post code. And this doesn't crash, so I even doubt it's my error. I just searched google looking for someone getting similar error and how to remove it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What error are you referring to?

Comment: Let me explain, there is no error. I'm just seeing a lot of garbage in my debug output which makes it really hard to see my own messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was running my Qt application and those strange outputs started to pop up in my application output window (in my Qt Creator). I noticed that the problem started after I installed an update for the Raptr (http://raptr.com/). I closed the Raptr application and the problem was solved. Raptr is usually installed when you install the drivers for your AMD graphics card. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I used Raptr for logging my time spent on games. Disabling it helped.

Comment: ltc_game.cpp shown in the log (unless you have a source with the same name) is from ltc_game64-11xxxx.dll (the version may differ) which is part of Raptr which hooks in to 3D applications to draw overlays etc. I ran in to it after my program was crashing with a stack overflow in that module.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same garbage, do you use some of this headers in you .h file

```
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QtSql>
```

I have been trying to locate where's the issue without success

Comment: No, I don't use these.