# VS developed program hooked by Raptr ltc_game

Tags: windbg

When debugging an application I am developing, using WinDbg, to my horror/surprise, I saw the following in the WinDbg window. I do have AMD graphics, am not a gamer, and have recently updated the graphics drivers.
In the following, I have changed the name of my exe file and the reported path to it, but nothing else. I know of no user named "Randal".
Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I have uninstalled Raptr. I think it was installed via the AMD update. But why would Raptr interfere with my own program in this way, and what else might it have been doing?

Thanks - extract from WinDbg log follows:

```
ModLoad: 65030000 65060000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationTypes\232495ea0368dada2d208c51f0e5349c\UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll
ModLoad: 62a70000 62afc000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll
ModLoad: 6b7c0000 6b7fc000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
ModLoad: 19310000 194ec000   C:\PROGRA~2\RAPTRI~1\Raptr\ltc_game32-111020.dll
[17:50:11.00848-110772] NotRealName.exe     dbglog.cpp(204)       DbgLog_F                       Log for module 'game' (111020) started with process 'NotRealName.exe' (x86, PID: 103208, CmdLine: C:\Users\[MyLegitimatePath]\NotRealName.exe) - Sun May 29 17:50:11 2016

[17:50:11.00848-110772] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5564)    DllMain                        Current process is an auto-hook candidate
[17:50:11.00850-110772] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2315)    StartAutoHookMonitoring        Auto-hook monitoring started
[17:50:11.00851-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5345)    MainThread                     MainThread executing...
[17:50:11.00851-109468] NotRealName.exe     autohook.cpp(265)     AutoHookManager::_WatchForQuitOrTimeoutThread Watching
[17:50:11.00851-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Console logging has been enabled.
[17:50:11.00851-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [sta:"StartRecorder"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [stp:"StopRecorder"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [slsk:"SetLiveStreamKey live_37135925_lD9UDVtrXfCT8yf0kHeWdVhaITG9oy"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [srl:"RecorderLog C:\Users\Randal\Desktop\ffmpeg.log"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [twitchtest2:"BroadcasterDebug 1;GetTwitchAuthToken ql7dn49ya6oalq5xux4s33a16n3e7sv RaptrRandal raptrtest"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [twitchtest:"BroadcasterDebug 1;SetTwitchAuthToken 1eduwz3hdp3yprib6vhpr5c64go2nv3;StartBroadcast"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [gfastfb:"GetFramebufferAsSizeFastBench 1"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Added alias [dt1:"D3D11FastDumpTest 1"]
[17:50:11.00853-111588] NotRealName.exe     console.h(158)        CConsole::Output               CONSOLE: Console initialised.
[17:50:11.00867-111588] NotRealName.exe     overlayui.cpp(1176)   OverlayUI_InitializeConsole    This game has no on-load flags.
[17:50:11.00868- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2813)    ModuleScanThread               ModuleScanThread executing...
[17:50:11.00869- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2820)    ModuleScanThread               Process File Name:NotRealName.exe
[17:50:11.00869- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2790)    LogRunningProcesses            Processes at startup:
[17:50:11.00869-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [0012270E] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00869-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [0007273E] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00870-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [00391916] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00871-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [0028094C] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00872-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [003D154E] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00872-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(4075)    EnumWindowsPrep                Window [003100D0] has been input-enabled.
[17:50:11.00873-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5397)    MainThread                     Waiting for shutdown event (00000DC0) or unload event...
[17:50:11.00882- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2804)    LogRunningProcesses            001.                 [System Process] PID      0 Parent PID:      0 Usage:      0 Threads:    8 Priority base:      0 Flags: 0x00000000
[17:50:11.00882- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2804)    LogRunningProcesses            002.                           System PID      4 Parent PID:      0 Usage:      0 Threads:  186 Priority base:      8 Flags: 0x00000000
[17:50:11.00884- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2804)    LogRunningProcesses            003.                         smss.exe PID    384 Parent PID:      4 Usage:      0 Threads:    2 Priority base:     11 Flags: 0x00000000
[17:50:11.00884- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2804)    LogRunningProcesses            004.                        csrss.exe PID    600 Parent PID:    592 Usage:      0 Threads:   11 Priority base:     13 Flags: 0x00000000
[17:50:11.00884- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2804)    LogRunningProcesses            005.                      wininit.exe PID    684 Parent PID:    592 Usage:      0 Threads:    3 Priority base:     13 Flags: 0x00000000

etc etc etc

[17:50:11.00926- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2887)    ModuleScanThread               147.    ltc_game32-111020.dll @ 0x19310000 - 0x194EBFFF Size: 1949696
[17:50:11.00926- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2909)    ModuleScanThread               Found Graphics Module:d3d9.dll bDelay:0
[17:50:11.00927- 96800] NotRealName.exe     com_hooks.cpp(197)    Direct3D9                      Installing d3d9.dll hooks...
[17:50:13.00562-110704] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2380)    OnGameRender                   Process: 0x000000FF System: 0x000000FF
[17:50:13.00563-110704] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2382)    OnGameRender                   Ideal processor is set to 5 (not changing)
[17:51:11.00852-109468] NotRealName.exe     autohook.cpp(257)     AutoHookManager::_WatchForQuitOrTimeout Timed-out
[17:51:11.00852-109468] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2298)    OnAutoHooked                   PID: 103208 timed-out
[17:51:11.00879- 96800] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(2948)    ModuleScanThread               Ending module scan thread...
[17:51:11.00879-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5405)    MainThread                     Unload game module event fired! Cleaning up...
[17:51:11.00880-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5457)    MainThread                     Shutdown capture
[17:51:11.00881-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5463)    MainThread                     Waiting for module scan thread...
[17:51:11.00885-111588] NotRealName.exe     com_hooks.cpp(207)    Direct3D9                      Removing d3d9.dll hooks...
[17:51:12.00174-111588] NotRealName.exe     winapi_hooks.cpp(977) DoHooking_WinAPI               WARNING! Cannot unhook, not hooked!
[17:51:12.00175-111588] NotRealName.exe     ltc_game.cpp(5528)    MainThread                     Shut down.

[end]
```

Comment: [Here's another debug output similar yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057998/unclear-error-log-in-visual-studio-2012). I wouldn't waste too much time trying to figure out how Raptr works. It's just a very invasive program in how it gets its hooks into other processes.

Comment: Did you restart the PC after uninstalling? This question probably better fits on SuperUser